# Slide and fade with Scriptaculous

Tags: scriptaculous

Is there a way to slide and fade at the same time in Scriptaculous. In Jquery you can use animate but not sure how with Scriptaculous to animate multiple properties on one element.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean slideUP()?
You can use Effect.Parallel():

```
new Effect.Parallel([
  new Effect.SlideUp(element, { sync: true, x: 20, y: -30, mode: 'relative' }), 
  new Effect.Fade(element, { sync: true, from: 1, to: 0 }) 
], { 
  duration: 0.8,
  delay: 0.5
});
```